# How do I invoke custom plugin on click?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have the following code:

```
(function(jQuery){
  jQuery.fn.timepicker = function(){
      return this.each(function(){
        jQuery(this).val("14:00");   
      });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Currently I invoke this function by the following code: `$("#event_start_time").timepicker();`

Where `#event_start_time` is the ID of an `<input>` field.

I do not want to invoke the plugin by using something like this:

```
$('#event_start_time"').click(function() {
  this.timepicker();
});
```

How can I invoke this code only when I click inside the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... this place isn't as quick as it used to be :(

I found the answer. Here's the code:

```
(function(jQuery){
  jQuery.fn.timepicker = function(){
      return this.each(function(){
        obj = $(this);
        obj.click(function () {
          alert('test');
        });
    });
    };
})(jQuery);
```